How can we add more than two phone numbers for whatsapp on Meta?
We are building an AI based tool users can communicate with our ai over Whatsapp. Its basically a chatbot. Cutomers provide their own whatsapp phone numbers and we connect the bot to that phonenumber.
We already have two customers and we need to onboard new customers. But on the panel we are prevented from adding more than two phone numbers. When I write to meta support, an automated bot responds that our account doesnt qualify to increse the phone number limit. How can we proceed?
Thanks in advance for any help

So where does that "Learn more" link lead to?
